# Host react App on Windows Server 2019 don't work

Tags: reactjs, windows-server-2019

I want to host my react application on port 3000 in windows server 2019.

I opened the port from windows defender following this article
https://epichosts.co.uk/articles/open-ports-windows
and run my application which listen on this port but it's not working.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show your program code?

Comment: @Ezani
The app working well on my localhost
I don't think that the problem from my code